415 unsupported media type when POSTing formdata from react to python using axios
Can't seem to figure it out. Every time I try to submit it gets to buildForm() and errors out with a 415 unsupported media type code. Backend is self made with flask, maybe I need to change something there? Here is my react code.
export default class AddForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      sn: "",
      name: "",
      qrcode: "",
      designator: "",
      subdesignator: "",
      oil: "",
      coolant: "",
      department: "",
      motor: "",
      data: [],
    };

    this.buildForm = this.buildForm.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  // handleSubmit(event) {
  //   console.log(event.target);
  // }
  buildForm() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("Specs[sn]", this.state.sn);
    formData.append("Specs[name]", this.state.name);
    formData.append("Specs[qrcode]", this.state.qrcode);
    formData.append("Specs[designator]", this.state.designator);
    formData.append("Specs[subdesignator]", this.state.subdesignator);
    formData.append("Specs[oil]", this.state.oil);
    formData.append("Specs[coolant]", this.state.coolant);
    formData.append("Specs[department]", this.state.department);

    return formData;
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    
    axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: `http://127.0.0.1:5000/Specs`,
      data: this.buildForm(),
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className="Searchbar">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="name"
              placeholder="Equipment Name"
              value={this.state.name}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              name="sn"
              placeholder="Serial Number"
              value={this.state.sn}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              name="department"
              placeholder="Department"
              value={this.state.department}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            // other inputs
          </div>
          <button type="submit">save</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

open to nearly anything. I have tried removing the unused state items and it didn't change anything. I have tried changing the wording in several parts. Postman works just fine to add data, and i can call the data up and see it.
    from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
    import os
    
    
    
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.sqlite')
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    ma = Marshmallow(app)
    
    class Specs(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        qrcode = db.Column(db.String, unique=False)
        sn = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=False)
        designator = db.Column(db.String(144), unique=False)
        subdesignator = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False)
        
        oil = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=False)
        coolant = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=False)
        department =db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False)
        motor = db.Column(db.String, unique=False)
        
    
    
        def __init__(self,qrcode,sn, name, designator, subdesignator,oil,coolant,department,motor):
            self.qrcode = qrcode
            self.sn = sn
            self.name = name
            self.designator = designator
            self.subdesignator = subdesignator
            
            self.oil = oil
            self.coolant = coolant
            self.department = department
            self.motor = motor
    
    
    
    class SpecsSchema(ma.Schema):
        class Meta:
            fields = ('qrcode','sn', 'name', 'designator', 'subdesignator','oil','coolant','department','motor')
    
    
    specs_schema = SpecsSchema()
    specss_schema = SpecsSchema(many=True)
    
    @app.route("/Specs", methods=["GET"])
    def get_specss():
        all_specs = Specs.query.all()
        result = specss_schema.dump(all_specs)
        return jsonify(result)
    
    
    @app.route("/Specs/<id>", methods=["GET"])
    def get_specs(id):
        specs = Specs.query.get(id)
        return specs_schema.jsonify(specs)
    
    
    
    @app.route("/Specs", methods=["POST"])
    def add_specs():
        qrcode = request.json['qrcode']
        sn = request.json['sn']
        name = request.json['name']
        designator = request.json['designator']
        subdesignator = request.json['subdesignator']
        
        oil = request.json['oil']
        coolant = request.json['coolant']
        department = request.json['department']
        motor = request.json['motor']
    
        new_specs = Specs(qrcode,sn, name, designator, subdesignator,oil,coolant,department,motor)
    
        db.session.add(new_specs)
        db.session.commit()
    
        specs = Specs.query.get(new_specs.id)
    
        return specs_schema.jsonify(specs)
    
    @app.route("/Specs/<sn>", methods=["PUT"])
    def specs_update(sn):
        specs = Specs.query.get(sn)
        qrcode = request.json['qrcode']
        sn = request.json['sn']
        name = request.json['name']
        designator = request.json['designator']
        subdesignator = request.json['subdesignator']
        oil = request.json['oil']
        coolant = request.json['coolant']
        department = request.json['department']
        motor = request.json['motor']
    
        Specs.qrcode = qrcode
        Specs.sn = sn
        Specs.name = name
        Specs.designator = designator
        Specs.subdesignator = subdesignator
        
        Specs.oil = oil
        Specs.coolant = coolant
        Specs.department = department
        Specs.motor = motor
    
        db.session.commit()
        return specs_schema.jsonify(specs)
    
    @app.route("/Specs/<sn>", methods=["DELETE"])
    def specs_delete(sn):
        specs = Specs.query.get(sn)
        db.session.delete(specs)
        db.session.commit()
    
        return "Specs were successfully deleted"
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)


added my app.py

also   there are no files. this is simple string and int data.

So my fix was to reshape my formData,
const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
    if (this.state.qrcode) {
      formData.append("qrcode", this.state.qrcode);
    }

    if (this.state.motor) {
      formData.append("motor", this.state.motor);
    }
    const data = Object.fromEntries(formData);
    console.log(event.currentTarget);
    console.log(data);
    axios
      .post(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/Specs`, data)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error", error);
      });
  }

but now I am getting an error "sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (sqlite3.ProgrammingError) Error binding parameter 2: type 'dict' is not supported"

and i am using picture files.

so I just needed to get further into the response data for the image files.
formData.append("qrcode", this.state.qrcode);

was turned into
formData.append("qrcode", this.state.qrcode.dataURL);

